# IdentityServer4 along with Asp.Net 4.5 MVC Client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

I am trying to authenticate an existing MVC application built with old Asp.Net (not the core version) with MVC framework.

By following IdentityServer4 and IdentityServer3 examples I have managed to get to a point where my user information is stored in LocalDB using EntityFramework and when I try to access to a restricted page in my client application I get redirected to the Login page provided by the IdentityServer4. However after successful login (based on what I see on the log) It does not redirect to the appropriate page. Address bar stays with something like http://localhost:5000/.... followed by lots of parameters and hashed values. Port 5000 is where I run my identity server and my application is hosted at port 44300 yet I couldn't manage to get back to there.

Has someone faced this kind of issue before or can someone please point me to an example which consists of IdentityServer4 along with a none Core version of Asp.Net.

### Edit 1: Implementation Details

**Server:** IdentityServer4 implementation is almost clone of IdentityServer4 Quickstarts 6-AspNetIdentity.

**Config File:**

```
public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };
    }

    // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        // client credentials client
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "webapp",
                ClientName = "Client WebApp",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:44300/signin-oidc" },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Client:** Client implementation I am using is a dummy and It originates from IdentityServer3 Client examples "MVC OWIN Client (Hybrid)".

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            Authority = "http://localhost:5000", //ID Server
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:44300/signin-oidc",
            ClientId = "webapp",

            ResponseType = "id_token code",
            Scope = "openid profile",
        });
    }
}
```

**Log Output:** Log output after clicking secured page -> IS Login Page -> Clicking Login.

```
...
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[3]
      HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Identity.Application.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/authorize/login matched to endpoint type Authorize
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Mapping found for endpoint: Authorize, creating handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize/login
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Start authorize request (after login)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      User in authorize request: df21b123-d4b6-40ef-beed-e918bdfd56e9
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Start authorize request protocol validation
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "webapp",
        "ClientName": "Client WebApp",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:44300/signin-oidc",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:44300/signin-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "df21b123-d4b6-40ef-beed-e918bdfd56e9",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "form_post",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
        "State": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=m1ybV84KFOLgklhcmtb8iR6VFuDBxWSzJKpTy83w7RF3zRTwd9zHBbdSyiAHbuea2D6FM1MjCJvMbql9qjcTntyu95POoCAWGwDML0nkiaYnKPKtJxgZ7FagyvYvz87C6pYlJWmL2zbrTFkYh7IPmX-Qv9rPOfyp4uwhhbZZ731vfL1mSxuhh_p1dPVNFJJav4E8bZXyadg94EXJbqb3ecc_jQHWn1F_eiJsoVMSRdk",
        "Nonce": "636268234716844341.OTFhNGE1ZTEtNTMyYy00Y2MyLWFjOGMtMDE1NjBmNDY3ZGM1NWFmNzIxMjItYTgzZC00NjJhLTk4YWMtNDExOTA0N2I4MjNl",
        "SessionId": "61d148313b2a7485dd27e3110ea61fff",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "webapp",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:44300/signin-oidc",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "response_type": "id_token code",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "state": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=m1ybV84KFOLgklhcmtb8iR6VFuDBxWSzJKpTy83w7RF3zRTwd9zHBbdSyiAHbuea2D6FM1MjCJvMbql9qjcTntyu95POoCAWGwDML0nkiaYnKPKtJxgZ7FagyvYvz87C6pYlJWmL2zbrTFkYh7IPmX-Qv9rPOfyp4uwhhbZZ731vfL1mSxuhh_p1dPVNFJJav4E8bZXyadg94EXJbqb3ecc_jQHWn1F_eiJsoVMSRdk",
          "nonce": "636268234716844341.OTFhNGE1ZTEtNTMyYy00Y2MyLWFjOGMtMDE1NjBmNDY3ZGM1NWFmNzIxMjItYTgzZC00NjJhLTk4YWMtNDExOTA0N2I4MjNl",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
          "x-client-ver": "1.0.40306.1554"
        }
      }
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [e].[Id], [e].[AccessFailedCount], [e].[ConcurrencyStamp], [e].[DefaultDatabaseName], [e].[DefaultDatabaseServer], [e].[Email], [e].[EmailConfirmed], [e].[HierarchyIds], [e].[LockoutEnabled], [e].[LockoutEnd], [e].[NormalizedEmail], [e].[NormalizedUserName], [e].[PasswordHash], [e].[PhoneNumber], [e].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [e].[SecurityStamp], [e].[TwoFactorEnabled], [e].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [e]
      WHERE [e].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing consent: User has not yet consented
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 138.8585ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/consent?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fconsent%3Fclient_id%3Dwebapp%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44300%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26response_type%3Did_token%2520code%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26state%3DOpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%253Dm1ybV84KFOLgklhcmtb8iR6VFuDBxWSzJKpTy83w7RF3zRTwd9zHBbdSyiAHbuea2D6FM1MjCJvMbql9qjcTntyu95POoCAWGwDML0nkiaYnKPKtJxgZ7FagyvYvz87C6pYlJWmL2zbrTFkYh7IPmX-Qv9rPOfyp4uwhhbZZ731vfL1mSxuhh_p1dPVNFJJav4E8bZXyadg94EXJbqb3ecc_jQHWn1F_eiJsoVMSRdk%26nonce%3D636268234716844341.OTFhNGE1ZTEtNTMyYy00Y2MyLWFjOGMtMDE1NjBmNDY3ZGM1NWFmNzIxMjItYTgzZC00NjJhLTk4YWMtNDExOTA0N2I4MjNl%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET%26x-client-ver%3D1.0.40306.1554
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[3]
      HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Identity.Application.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 32.5652ms 404
```

Comment: Can you give more details, such as the flow/grant-type you're using and show your client definition.

Comment: I have edited my post to provide related settings code.

Answer (score 0):

Your application running an older version of .NET isn't relevant.
[In this video](https://vimeo.com/171942749), one of the authors of IdentityServer demonstrates how he was able to connect a WinForm application with IDS4.

The communication to the IDS4 is made through HTTP requests, your client could be anything really as long as it can handle the communication with the IDS4.
I suggest that you open fiddler and monitor the requests to view the parameters passing.
You could also use one of the [quickstarts](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html) as a base to your IDS, or compare it to your setup to check what's wrong.

Comment: As you said my understanding was that the client wouldn't matter yet I couldn't managed to get it work yet.

I have followed the IdentityServer4 and IdentityServer3 examples to implement a test server and client.

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it is showing that your user has not yet consented to the scopes being requested and so is attempting to navigate to a page on the Identity Server where the user can consent.

```
`Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/consent?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fconsent%3Fclient_id%3Dwebapp%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44300%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26response_type%3Did_token%2520code%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26state%3DOpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%253Dm1ybV84KFOLgklhcmtb8iR6VFuDBxWSzJKpTy83w7RF3zRTwd9zHBbdSyiAHbuea2D6FM1MjCJvMbql9qjcTntyu95POoCAWGwDML0nkiaYnKPKtJxgZ7FagyvYvz87C6pYlJWmL2zbrTFkYh7IPmX-Qv9rPOfyp4uwhhbZZ731vfL1mSxuhh_p1dPVNFJJav4E8bZXyadg94EXJbqb3ecc_jQHWn1F_eiJsoVMSRdk%26nonce%3D636268234716844341.OTFhNGE1ZTEtNTMyYy00Y2MyLWFjOGMtMDE1NjBmNDY3ZGM1NWFmNzIxMjItYTgzZC00NjJhLTk4YWMtNDExOTA0N2I4MjNl%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET%26x-client-ver%3D1.0.40306.1554`
```

This step takes place before redirecting back to your calling website, so I'm guessing you haven't implemented this page on IdSvr yet,

Comment: I have checked the example I followed to see how I can create those pages. I will keep looking for it but I have noticed this information:
Url: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

It says use RequireConsent = false, in clients configuration and I tried it yet the outcome is same.